# Android: placing button below multiline textview

Tags: android, eclipse, button, textview

I am designing an Android application and I'm stuck. Tried a lot of thing but nothing helped so far.
I have an activity with multiple TextViews and buttons.
One of those textviews holds an address, but it can be multiline. So sometimes it has 1 line, other times up to maximum 4.
Now i want to place a button underneath. When the textview only has 1 line, no problem, but when it has more, the text goes over my button.
Here is are the views in my XML file:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/locatie"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/locatie"
   android:text="@string/mapknop" />
```

I have tried many things like min lines and max lines on my textview but nothing's working. Anyone has a solution?
Thanks

EDIT:
here is my complete XML File

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/evenement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/affiche"
        android:onClick="showImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uren"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datum"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DETAILS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/uren"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/details"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DETAILS"
        android:text="@string/vvk"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/kassa"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/locatie"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vvk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kassa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vvk"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <!--  PROBLEM OCCURS FROM HERE -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locatie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kassa"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locatie"
        android:text="@string/mapknop" />

      <!--  UNTIL HERE -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/omschrijving"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/omschrijving"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lineup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:text="@string/lineup"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lineup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/omschrijving"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: here are screenshots of 1 line vs 2 lines

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TU44.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/igAXd.jpg

Comment: post your whole xml file please

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your xml, post complete layout xml.

Comment: I think,atleast something is wrong in xml,you can look at this lines,android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Comment: edited my post, see the comments where the problem occurs, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Edittext in place of TextView that will be better.
And here is the code sample which is working for me and hope will work fine for you.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/locatie"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:hint="locatie"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLength="32"
    android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKJLZXCVBNM0123456789- "/>
```